# Is there a word that means "influential location/place"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that could be used to represent a city (e.g. New York), or a building (e.g. the US Capitol), or even a sacred site of some sort (e.g. Mauna Kea).

Preferably a noun, but a single adjective could work too.

"Influencer" and "sanctum" were the closest ones I've found, but they don't seem to contextually fit well enough to convey such a meaning on their own, if that makes sense.

If it helps, I'd be using the word to represent a card type in politically themed board game. So, the ultimate goal of the word is to assist in teaching game's mechanisms.

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by an example sentence: could you do that? That said, there probably isn't one word. The word will be defined by why the place is significant and perhaps who finds it significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about . . .

> **Mecca**, *n.*
>
> **II.** Simple uses
> **3.** A place regarded as supremely sacred or valuable, or where a faith, policy, truth, etc., originates. Also more generally: a place
> which attracts people of a particular group or with a particular
> interest; a resort *of* (also *for*) a certain group of people.
>
> <sub>Source: [Oxford English Dictionary](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

Although the OED capitalizes the word, it usually appears lowercase in this usage.

For more ideas, [see *mecca* synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/mecca)

Comment: Yes, this one could work. I will likely either use this, or "cornerstone", depending on how things play out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding buildings: 'landmark'

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/landmark

*Examples of landmark in a Sentence:*

```
 *The Golden Gate Bridge is a famous landmark in San Francisco.*
```

Regarding both buildings and cities: 'destination':

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/destination

*Examples of destination in a Sentence:*

```
 *After stopping for lunch, we continued on toward our destination.*
```

More general term: 'attraction'

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attraction

*Examples of attraction in a Sentence:*

```
 *The waterfall continues to be the main attraction at the park.*
```

Answer (score -1):

**sight** (n.)

> A thing seen, esp. of a striking or remarkable nature; a spectacle.
> OED

---

> **New York City** is a **sight** to be seen, and it is best viewed from
> the designated spot. [Pramod Nayar; *Reading Culture*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reading_Culture/8FiPb3JCmy0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22New%20york%20city%20is%20a%20sight%22&pg=PA199&printsec=frontcover)

> The Prince of Wales, who has just left our shores, said that **New
> York City** was a **sight** the like of which he had never before
> imagined, and Mr. Alesbury remarked that he entirely agreed with the
> prince. [*The Vehicle Monthly*, Dec., 1919, p.54](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Motor_Body_Paint_and_Trim/--w_AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22The%20Prince%20of%20Wales%22)

> The **US Capitol** is the most prominent **sight** in Washing DC and
> an essential stop for anyone with a political bent. [*The Rough Guide
> to the USA*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Rough_Guide_to_the_USA/Ca0AAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=The%20U.S.%20capitol%20is%20a%20%20sight&pg=PT318&printsec=frontcover)

> At 4,207 meters above sea level, **Mauna Kea** is superb for astronomy
> and a rare **sight** to behold. [Andrew Crusoe; *Then Thousand Hours
> in Paradise: Arrival*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Ten_Thousand_Hours_in_Paradise/imKGDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Mauna%20Kea%20sight&pg=PT146&printsec=frontcover)

> These place are: Lumbini, (birthplace of Buddha, Nepal); Bodhgaya (the place of Buddha's enlightenment)... Although
> not limited to these **sights**, these places have become sacred foci
> for the convergence of multiple expressions of Buddhist devotion that
> cut across national, cultural-linguistic, and sectarian lines.
> Collectively and individually, these **sacred sites** are visited by
> hundreds of thousands of devotees and nondevotees that are drawn to
> the "spiritual magnetism"...of place but also the medling of Buddhist
> teachings, culture, and heritage values as popular religious and
> tourist spaces. [Kiran Shinde; *Sacred Sites, Rituals, and
> Performances*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Sacred_Sites_Rituals_and_Performances/wyZCEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=sacred%20sites%20are%20sights&pg=PA99&printsec=frontcover)

> Almost half of the important national scenic spots contain religious
> **sights**, excluding those religious **sites** in the less well-known tourist scenic spots, which reflects the positive role that religious
> culture plays in the protection of the eco-environment. [R. Raj and N.
> Morpeth; *Religious Tourism and Pilgrimage Festivals Management*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Religious_Tourism_and_Pilgrimage_Festiva/E9dPorLfIlQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=some%20sights%20are%20sacred%20sites&pg=PA109&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I see what you were going for here, and I think it makes sense. I am looking for a word that is a bit more contextual, though. Thank you so much!